# Android sending simple data -- app can share to it self?

Tags: android

I have an application which has a file browser and a created image viewer. In these activities we can share.

I added the option to receive simple data (shares) from other applications by adding the the manifest

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg" />
        </intent-filter>
```

The issue is, I receive shares from elsewhere no problem. I share within the application, I can select, my application. I would like it to not be sharable to my application from my application. I see apps such as the samsung gallery does not suffer this annoying problem (which means there is a fix and I cannot ignore it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Samsung gallery app actually does not show up in its own share menu because you cannot *share* files via that app, but only *view* them.

If you are severly annoyed by your app appearing in the system-built chooser dialog, you could always build your own. Simply get all the apps that you could use for sending via [`PackageManager.queryIntentActivities(android.content.Intent, int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29), then display them in a custom dialog.